# A series of jointly distributed discrete random variables questions

Tags: probability

> Suppose X and Y are jointly distributed discrete random variables, with probability mass function $P_x,y$(x,y)= ${k(1-\theta)^x(\theta)^y\over y! }$ where x,y = 0,1,2,... and $0<\theta<1$
>
> 1) Find out k 
>   
>   2) Are X and Y independent? why?
>   
>   3) Find $E(X^y)$

I am kinda stuck at first one, does this kind of probability mass function have anything to do with $\sum\sum f(x,y)=1$  ?
and second one is to test if it's p(x)p(y)?

thanks to any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to find the "double sum," set it equal to $1$. First let us sum with respect to $y$.  We get
$$k(1-\theta)^x\sum_0^\infty \frac{\theta^y}{y!}.$$
You should recognize the inner sum as $e^\theta$. It is more familiar with different letters: the power series expansion of $e^x$ is $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$.

Now we want to sum with respect to $x$. So we want 
$$ke^\theta\sum_0^\infty(1-\theta)^x.$$
You will recognize the sum as an infinite geometric series with sum $\frac{1}{1-(1-\theta)}=\frac{1}{\theta}$.

For the second problem, yes the key thing, as you observed, is that the joint distribution function factors as $f(x)g(y)$.

You did not ask about the third problem, so I will only say that it involves sum procedures closely related to the procedure used in the first problem.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope thing are clear. If any questions remain, just ask.

Comment: so for the first one, it equals to $K*1 \over \theta e^\theta$ and equals to 1 right? but i suddenly don't have a clue here..

Comment: The double sum, by the calculation above, is $\frac{ke^\theta}{\theta}$. To make this equal to $1$, you need $k=\frac{\theta}{e^\theta}=\theta e^{-\theta}$.

Comment: oh right! lol sorry for this..

Comment: I see the second one using $f(x)g(y)$, but what does it equal to?

Comment: also the third question, how do i get a clear look at what X and y are and do the calculation?

Comment: Someone [asked that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466621/finding-exy) today, and I answered it in full detail.